# Visual Studio C++ Google Test not recognizing TEST macro after checkout from Version Control

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, googletest

I'd like to test my C++ Project with the google test Framework. I work with Visual Studio 2017 and have ReSharper c++ installed. 
In addition I want to use subversion.
I created a Solution with only one Google Test project. I did everything according to the following article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2017
Everything works fine so far. Visual Studio and ReSharper both find the test and can run it as expected. It also finds the TEST macro as well as the ASSERT_ and EXPECT_ macros.

I don't want the package and .vs folder in subversion. So all I check in are following the files: .sln, .vcxproj, .vcxproj.user, pch.h, pch.cpp, packages.config and the test.cpp as well as the folders.

If I check this out in another directory, the Solution builds just fine. The google test package gets downloaded as expected and a new .vs folder is generated. But the problem is, that the TEST macro is not recognized as a macro anymore. It is marked red and i get a "Function 'Test' must have return type" message when I hover over it and the EXPECT_ Macros are also red and I get a "Cannot resolve symbol 'EXPECT_EQ'" message. At this Point ReSharper does not find any tests anymore. But the Visual Studio test explorer does! I can even run it from the test explorer and get a green test.

At this point I thought it might be a problem with Resharper and turned it off. This did solve the problem in the small solution with only the one test project. After building and reopening visual studio everything worked again. So I implemented it in my bigger solution I am working on, but even after building the solution and reopening the Visual Studio the macros are still not recognized! I can build and run the tests from the test explorer and hovering over the TEST macro now shows a slightly different message : "explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)" and hovering over the EXPECT_EQ macro now prints "identifier 'EXPECT_EQ' undefined".

Does anyone know why the studio does not recognize the Macros anymore and how I can fix it?

Comment: Uninstall Resharper, make sure that intellisense is enabled, use Rescan Solution command to refresh intellisense data. Also using subversion in 2018 does not look like a good idea

Comment: @VTT Thanks for your answere. Unfortunately the problem still remains.